# What are the possibilities to make a personal landing page?

Tags: design

I am asked to create a personal landing page for each user after they login so they see their contact info and relevant related info.

Even if I were open to make a VF page, how to set it up?

I need workable design ideas.

Comment: Setup > Customize > Home

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow this design -

1) Create a visualforce Page and create a Vf Tab using the same.

2) Make this Vf Tab the default landing Tab for all the users.

3) Write business logic inside Vf page's controller to drive/navigate users based on the requirements.

Hope this helps. Please mark it as answer if you find this useful.

-SK